# Does google cloud support managing customer domains?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I am creating a SaaS application using Google cloud, and my customers have to map their domain names to my application, does Google cloud support this?

So I have my application, lets say it is a CMS application.

So every customer will have their own domain name, and CNAME map their domain to point to my domain like:

**customer1 will point to**

```
   service.my-saas.com
```

where my-saas.com is the application hosted on google cloud.

Or if my customer doesn't have their own domain, it would be:

```
customer1.my-saas.com
```

Is this something that google cloud supports?

From what I remember it doesn't support wildcard mappings or custom domains it an automated fashion.

Comment: Can you clarify with GCP service you are using? How to use custom domains effectively is different on GAE, GCE, GKE, Cloud Functions etc.

Comment: I was thinking of using GAE.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible:

1. [Add a custom domain](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains/add). Use my-saas.com as the domain, and then enter *.my-saas.com for subdomain.
2. Modify your DNS so that *.my-saas.com has a CNAME pointint to ghs.googlehosted.com.
3. Your application can then use the contents of the host header to detect which customer site is being accessed by a given request, and return the correct data.

If you want each customer's site to run different code or run on separate instances, deploy each customer in a separate service, and then use [dispatch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref) to route each domain to a different service. This is limited to 20 customers.